# Extract `setup` code chunk from `.qmd` file and execute (source) it

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, quarto

I am looking for a way to extract a code block / chunk named `setup` from a `.qmd` file and execute the code block (effectively sourcing it, I assume).

Is there a way of achieving this?

I am using `rmarkdown::yaml_front_matter()$params` to get the parameter, but looking into other functions in the `knits` package did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have `foo.qmd` like this:

````markdown
---
output: revealjs
---

```{r setup}
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
```

```{r}
iris
```
````

You can use [`parsermd`](https://github.com/rundel/parsermd) to parse the file and extract the item you want (code chunks, headings, etc.). Then, remove the elements from the markdown syntax and evaluate the code:

````r
library(parsermd)
  
rmd <- parse_rmd("foo.qmd")
  
setup_chunk <- rmd_select(rmd, "setup") |> 
  as_document()

setup_chunk <- setup_chunk[-grep("```", setup_chunk)]
setup_chunk
#> [1] "library(tidyr)"   "library(stringr)" ""                

eval(parse(text = setup_chunk))
````

An alternative is to write `setup_chunk` to a file and `source()` it.

Comment: Great - exactly what I was looking or. I will come back if it does not work.

Comment: @Rainer Actually no need to use any other package for this task---`knitr::knit_code$get('setup')` gives you the code.

Comment: That is great. I have to look more into the knits package and the get function. Thanks @YihuiXie

Comment: @YihuiXie Looking at it again now - I would like to do this from a normal R session and I have only the file name of the `.qmd` file - can I still use `knitr::knit_code$get('setup')`? Background: running individual code chunks in VSCode which require the setup code.